# What storage method 2 use 4 saving and deleting .txt files programmatically on specific external storage, and loading .txt files on android 11?

Tags: android, directory, storage, external

I looked up scoped storage but that won't work because of the permission request seeing my apps feature has to delete files on backpress (if user changes folder name)/ onstop, and also multiple .txt files need to be loaded when user restores/backsup notes.

Media store doesnt say anything about .txt files nor about deleting them, that i could find. And it cant be public storage(documents or downloads) because it also writes to folder name that user types. Any help would be great, currently app is rejected from using manage_external_storage. It seems like manage external storage is the only way to go.
Thanks

this is my current code

```
  FileUtil.writeFile(FileUtil.getExternalStorageDir().
  concat("/Folder/text.txt"), e2.getText().toString());

  FileUtil.deleteFile(FileUtil.getExternalStorageDir().
  concat("/Folder/text.txt"));
```

Comment: It is unclear what your problem is. Or what is it that you want to do but does nit go?

Comment: I re edited the post, sorry in hurry lately since they rejected my app.

Comment: I looked more into SAF and it looks l would have to grant permission anytime file is deleted or moved. But i notice other apps not even having a permission request and still write to storage specific folders i choose. Though i havent seen them delete files yet which my app does on the fly.

Comment: `But wondering am i wrong could i use media store for all that? `. For the second time: what is it that you want and have problems with?

Comment: `l would have to grant permission anytime file is deleted or moved.` In general: that is not true.

Comment: `and still write to storage specific folders i choose They have lower target version. And we dont know about which folders you are takking

Comment: This is what i used pre 11 with write and read external storage permissions, now it dont work unless i use manage external storage which gets rejected? I looked up a few others ways but they all either save to documents or ask permission every time. I dont think i can explain any further than this unless your trolling me. 
   FileUtil.writeFile(FileUtil.getExternalStorageDir().concat("/Folder/text.txt"), e2.getText().toString());
FileUtil.deleteFile(FileUtil.getExternalStorageDir().concat("/Folder/text.txt"));

Comment: I will not read code in comments. Unreadable. Put it in your post. No trolling.