# Cant retrieve text from intent filter in textview, on opening browser file

Tags: android, android-intent, text, filter, mime

I'm trying to get the text when a .txt file is selected. But im only getting this back content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A52139. Im just barely getting to uri's and dont quite understand them yet
Thanks I have this in on create of MainActivity

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String act = i.getAction();
if (act.equals("android.intent.action.VIEW")){t.setText 
(i.getData().toString());
```

And this in manifest

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category. 
BROWSER"/>
<data android:scheme="content"/>
<data android:mimeType="text/plain">
<data android:mimeType="image/*">
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.
BROWSER"/>
<data android:scheme="content"/>
<data android:mimeType="text/plain">
<data android:mimeType="image/*">
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: What you get isn't the text, what you get is a content provider URL. You need to open that and read in the text. See answers to this for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069556/android-read-text-file-from-uri

Comment: Yes that worked forgot to add Intent i = getIntent(); then change data to i,  at beginning they should have included that also thanks

Comment: Can you answer this one also   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70702522/what-storage-method-2-use-4-saving-and-deleting-txt-files-programmatically-on-s?noredirect=1#comment125019585_70702522